# How to add two setup procedures in BehaviorSearch

Tags: netlogo, behaviorsearch

In my Netlogo model, my setup procedure is under two headings load1 and load2 and I want to add both under the setup in BehaviorSearch. I tried to specify both using comma (load1, load2) but i am getting an error when running the BehaviorSearch.
How can I do that (see figure below)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb4Dj.png)?

Thanks very much for your help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byq3Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one setup procedure called by BehaviorSpace. The easiest way to do something like that would be to create a procedure that calls both and then simply use that as your setup:

```
to setup
  load1
  load2
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It addressed my issue, and your help is highly appreciated as a new learner of NetLogo, Thanks